# Unable to set class level variable in Angular 2 Inside Callback

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I'm sure it's something small that I'm missing, and I'll be the first to tell you I'm no Angular or ES6 expert. I have the following code set:

```
getScanner(){
    var that = this;
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
       function (result) {
            console.log("OBJ "+result);

            that.data = result;

            //THIS IS DEFINED
            console.log("That data first is "+that.data);

             alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                     "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                     "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                     "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);              
        }, 
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );

    //THIS IS UNDEFINED
    console.log("That data is finally "+that.data);

}
```

As you can see above, when I first set that.data inside the callback, it printed to the console fine. Then, somehow it's losing reference once I get to the console.log outside of the Cordova call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the promise? Looks like you're using callbacks.

Comment: This whole snippet cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan is straight from their example. This is the plugin api. The only thing I wrote was the console logs and variables.

Comment: Okay, but there's no promise anywhere, even though it would be a good idea to promisify it to make it easier to write the code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` call is asynchronous, so `that.data` will not be defined until after the success callback is invoked.

If you look at your console, you should notice that the `"That data is finally"` message is logged *before* the `"That data first is"` message.

Comment: I'm following, but what's the proper way to use that.data after the success has finished?

Comment: You'd use it in the success handler.

Comment: This helped me find a solution to my problem. Thanks a lot!